# VMware Fusion: transfer programs/config from one Windows to another

Tags: vmware-fusion

Both virtual machines on VMWare Fusion - with the first one, it is impossible to connect to the internet, so I installed another XP.

What I want to do is to import all the programs in the new one.

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot!
Franky

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  Windows doesn't support moving programs from one desktop to another, whether they're virtual or physical.  You'll need your original install media for the software.

Settings, on the other hand, is doable.  Use the File and Settings Transfer Wizard:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457074.aspx

Forget that they're running under Fusion.  Just use the Wizard to transfer data via a USB key or CD/DVD burner from machine to machine.